# Comando SQL no C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Bom eu estou fazendo um crud utilizando o mvc e o entity framework, só que não sei como faço a passagem de parâmetros... aqui esta meu código

```
public void Cadastrar(TimeModel timeObj)
{   
    strQuery = "INSERT INTO TimeFut (nome, estado) VALUES (aqui vai os parâmetros)";
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(strQuery);
}
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Se pretende utilizar comandos "manuais" não precisa utilizar o Entity Framework. O bom de utilizar um ORM é que não precisamos nos preocupar com CRUD "manual". Dê uma olhada a alguns artigos sobre CRUD + EF na web e logo percebe o que quero dizer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um objeto `SqlParameter` para cada parâmetro que você precisar.

Para adicionar parâmetros na query basta utilizar `@nomeDaVariavel`, e no `SqlParameter` você passa o nome do parâmetro sem o arroba e o valor do parâmetro:

```
string nomeEstado = "Minas Gerais";
string query = @"INSERT INTO TimeFut (nome, estado) VALUES (@nome, @estado)";
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, 
                              new SqlParameter("nome", "Pedro Paulo"),
                              new SqlParameter("estado", nomeEstado));
```

Comment: Muito obg, deu certo, muito obrigado mesmo